# Extracting data from dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, urllib

I have a program from Dr.Chuck to print the sum of the counts from this data. The problem is. The count of the JSON is showing "2" when there are many..

```
import json
import urllib

url="http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json"
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
print data

info = json.loads(data)
print 'User count:', len(info)
```

This line `print 'User count:', len (info)` is showing an output of 2. When there is a lot of data, hence I can only access 2 datas and not the rest.

I have no idea why. I can solve the counting sum part. Just not getting why am I only getting access to the first 2 data and the rest of the JSON is getting ignored.

Comment: Donno who gave the downvote :( and why.. I'm a newbie hence asked this question. I will get barred unnecessarily :/ 
Thanks a lot histrio, Millie, Stefano, and stoffen additionally for solving the rest program as well :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json has two top level properties: note and comments. That is why you get a length of 2.

This will probably give you what you want:

```
len(info["comments"])
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of comments:

```
print 'User count:', len(info["comments"])
```

To print the total "count":

```
count = 0
for comment in info["comments"]:
    count += comment["count"]
print 'Total count:', count
```

Answer (score 1):

So, your json parsed to dict like

```
{"note":"bla", "comments":[...]}
```

Length of this should be 2 because it's only two keys in this dict. Right way to do you case is get comments itself and count them.

For example:

```
len(data.get('comments',[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Json is composed from note and comments. Inside comments there's another array of object.
if you wanna access to that array you have to use this `info['comments']` and then, if you want the length of that array, as you do, you can use `len(info['comments'])`

Comment: thanks Stefano :) Im a newbie to Python.. thanks for helping out